# Docker windows with hyper-v example baffles me??? Why does the alpine example not work they way I thought it would?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, hyper-v, docker-machine

I am hoping an expert on Docker who uses Windows gets to read this as I really do not understand this at all.

I installed Docker on my Windows 10 machine, no vmware just hyper-v, all works great until I tried to create volumes from my local machine and use them within my Linux containers, this is when my problems start.

Within docker is an example to try to see how the volumes work:

[image]

I created a directory within my Users directory and a simple file just to see something within the alpine container.

[image]

But when I run the following command I get no files within the steve/work directory?

[image]

Where on earth is afile.txt???

Sorry if I am being a bit stupid but I have created volumes on Linux machines without any problems and I just dont get where on earth my files are? How can I dev on a Windows machine and get my source code into my containers without needing to perform Dockerfile copies of all my source files into the container??

Just for further confusion (probably on my part!) but when I execute the same command and look into just the steve folder I can see the work folder as expected but I also see a folder called work#? So the work folder is there (even if I delete it???)

[image]

I am just really really confused about how to create volumes on a Windows machine using Hyper-V.

Many thanks in advance.
P.S If you have any links which actually explain differences between the Windows Hyper-V Docker and Linux Docker I would also be very very grateful as I cant find any or documents which mix information regarding Windows with just Hyper-V and VMWare.

Thanks again...

Answer (score 3):

**SOLVED!**

After hours and hours of research and messing around with Windows Docker I have volumes sharing correctly between my Windows host machine and a Linux container. Which means I can see files within my container which exist on my local Windows machine.

My research got me to this link [THE ANSWER AND TONS OF GREAT INFO ON THIS PROBLEM](https://forums.docker.com/t/volume-mounts-in-windows-does-not-work/10693/67)

The answer which works and makes total sense is by a guy called 'dennisfischer', although the forum entry is long its well worth reading to get the background of the problem and to get a handle on what is going on between Windows fs and the container.

Anyway hopefully this may save you a hell of a lot of time!

P.S Cheers to Philip who was really helpful, thanks for the messages and hopefully this will be of some use to you at some point.

Comment: Glad to hear it helped you! It took me about two full days to find that but at least that's is a working answer now!

Answer (score 0):

I just went through the same exercise with a new copy of Windows 10 Enterprise running in a VMWare Fusion vm.

The first thing you must do is to open the docker settings app, available from your app tray (or whatever it's called in Windows). Then select Sharing and share the drives you want to explore with. When you click Apply, you will be prompted with a username password dialog. Enter that and an example shown there will actually work. I setup test.user and then was able to do:

`run -it --rm -v C:/Users:/data alpine ls /data`

One more caveat though. I was logged into with a domain login through a business account via Office 365. my domainname\username did not work. Instead I had to create a local windows user and supply that. This will cause some extra headaches with permissions no doubt, but seems to be the only option at the moment. It is possible that had I been connected in my workplace this may have worked, but since I work at home and will be speaking at a conference next week, no joy for me!

Comment: Cheers Philip can I just ask, I got what I thought was working with the alpine image but I only got my user folder showing (steve) but the files which are definitely in they're just don't show? Anyway I have moved forward with volumes instead which appear to work as i expect. But I still cannot run a Linux image and see folder with files from my Windows file system?

Comment: I saw something similar. No errors with the volume argument, but also no files showing. I had to do the sharing setup first, and supply credentials and then it worked. If I then tried to map a folder that local user I supplied did not have access to, I actually got a useful error. Had you already done the sharing setup?

Comment: Well I know this sounds a bit nooby but I think so? I used the docker task panel app by the time and set sharing at drive level C & D on my machine, and yes I was asked for credentials which must be correct (I say that based on if they are correct I get no acknowledgement but if I enter rubbish docker does actually reject and ask for the credentials again!) but I have never seen any files within a Linux container which are - v'ed from the local machine with the run command?

Comment: Just out of interest Philip but can you run up a docker container of say busybox and use the '- v local:cont mount' and see your windows files from within the running busybox Linux container?

Comment: If the credentials are incorrect then it prompts again and again. If you go back in and those drives are still checked, you should be fine. Here is the command I used to try out your busybox question ```docker run -it --rm -v C:/:/data busybox ls /data``` It did work as expected. I choose C:\ because there is unlikely to be permission issues there.  You could also do ```docker run -it --rm -v C:/:/data busybox /bin/sh``` and poke around yourself.

Comment: PS, as an example, I was able with busybox and that /bin/sh arg to use the "linux" commands to list ProgramData/Git under the C:/ I had mapped.

Comment: Ok philip firstly thanks for all your time, very much appreciated and great to communicate with someone who has this working. But I went into the docker tool app thingy by the clock bottom right and yes my drives are all showing shared and I believe they are shared and my credentials are correct. I then ran the command you used as this must work, I get the data folder but its totally empty not a single file within it. I then executed the shell to have a look myself and sure enough the data  folder is totally empty??? I have no idea why my docker just does not map files from windows into Linux?

Comment: Just out of interest you are using hyper-v and not vmware?

Comment: hyper-v yes. Just curious. If you don't remove the image, say ```docker run -it  --name bb -v C:/:/data busybox ls /data ``` so the container is still there, what do you see in the Mounts section of  ```docker inspect bb```. Mine shows this ```"Mounts": [
            {
                "Source": "/C",
                "Destination": "/data",
                "Mode": "",
                "RW": true,
                "Propagation": "rprivate"
            } ```

Comment: "Mounts": [
    {
        "Source": "/C",
        "Destination": "/data",
        "Mode": "",
        "RW": true,
        "Propagation": "rprivate"
    }
],

Comment: "Mounts": [
    {
        "Source": "/C",
        "Destination": "/data",
        "Mode": "",
        "RW": true,
        "Propagation": "rprivate"
    }
],

Comment: yep! I'm out of ideas, sorry!

Comment: Thanks Philip much appreciated!